# Problemas ao ler um PDF com imagem com TESS4J

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

Recentemente comecei a desenvolver um pequeno jar executável que converte PDF para arquivos de textos e o mesmo vai funcionar em ambiente Windows.

Utilizando a o TESS4J 3.3.1, desenvolvi o seguinte processo:

A) O usuário poderá escolher inserir um PDF ou uma imagem;

B) Caso seja um PDF, o sistema vai converter para imagem usando o GHOST4J;

C) A imagem será convertida em texto usando o TESS4J.

Para a maioria dos arquivos testados o programa funcionou corretamente, mas quando eu inseri um arquivo de nota fiscal (em PDF) com um logotipo, o programa (no ponto C) não consegue converter nem 10% da imagem em texto.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.ghost4j.document.PDFDocument;
import org.ghost4j.renderer.SimpleRenderer;

public class PDFToImage {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss");

    public static List<File> convert(File filePDF) throws Exception{
        PDFDocument document = new PDFDocument();
        try {
            document.load( new FileInputStream( filePDF ) );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }

        SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer();
        renderer.setResolution( 300 );

        List<Image> renderedImageList = null;
        try {
            renderedImageList = renderer.render(document);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

        List<File> fileImageList = new ArrayList<File>();
        try {
            for( Image i : renderedImageList ){
                File f = new File( "C:\\Users\\story\\Desktop\\ocr_test" + File.separator + filePDF.getName() + "_" + renderedImageList.indexOf( i ) + sdf.format( new Date() ) + ".png" ); 
                ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) i, "png", f);
                fileImageList.add( f );
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

        return fileImageList;
    }

}
```

Arquivo de teste:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import net.sourceforge.tess4j.ITesseract;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException;

public class Basic  {

    // Teste: A, B e C
//  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
//      File pdfFile = new File("C:\\Users\\story\\Desktop\\ocr_test\\source_pdf.pdf");
//
//      List<File> imageList = PDFToImage.convert(pdfFile);
//
//      ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
//      instance.setLanguage("eng");
//      instance.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\story\\Desktop\\ocr_test\\tessdata");
//
//      for( File i : imageList ){
//          try {
//              String result = instance.doOCR( i );
//              System.out.println(result);
//          } catch (TesseractException e) {
//              System.err.println(e.getMessage());
//          }
//      }
//  }

    // Teste: B e C
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
        instance.setLanguage("eng");
        instance.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\story\\Desktop\\ocr_test\\tessdata");
        try {
            String result = instance.doOCR( new File("C:\\Users\\story\\Desktop\\ocr_test\\source_png_split.png") );
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Imagem do PDF com problema:

[image: Cabeçalho do PDF com problema, se eu remover esse logotipo ele funciona perfeitamente]

Caso eu remova (no paint mesmo) esse logotipo, a imagem é convertida perfeitamente! Nesse caso eu estou com as duvidas:

1) No TESS4J: existe um meio de impedir esse erro?

2) No GHOST4J: existe alguma maneira de não converter essa imagem no PDF para a imagem final?

Answer (score -1):

Eu consegui resolver o problema! Após pesquisar um pouco mais no Google, eu modifiquei um pouco a classe PDFToImage.java consegui resolver o problema de duas formas distintas:

```
package core;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.ghost4j.document.PDFDocument;
import org.ghost4j.renderer.SimpleRenderer;

import util.Utils;

public class PDFToImage {

    private static final ResourceBundle properties = ResourceBundle.getBundle( "properties/configuration" );
    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss");

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static List<File> convert(File preFilePDF, Class clazz) throws Exception {
        // Inicio trecho adicionado
        File filePDF = preFilePDF;

        if( Boolean.parseBoolean( properties.getString("PDF_STAMP_IMAGE") ) ){
            filePDF = PDFStamper.convert( preFilePDF, clazz);
        }

        if( Boolean.parseBoolean( properties.getString("PDF_REMOVE_IMAGE") ) ){
            filePDF = PDFRemoveImage.convert( preFilePDF );
        }
        // Fim trecho adicionado

        PDFDocument document = new PDFDocument();
        try {
            document.load( new FileInputStream( filePDF ) );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }

        SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer();
        renderer.setResolution( 300 );

        List<Image> renderedImageList = null;
        try {
            renderedImageList = renderer.render(document);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

        if( !filePDF.canExecute() 
                && !filePDF.canExecute()
                && !filePDF.canRead() ){
            throw new Exception("Sem permissão na pasta "+filePDF.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        List<File> fileImageList = new ArrayList<File>();
        try {
            for( Image i : renderedImageList ){
                File f = new File( "C:\\Users\\story\\Desktop\\ocr_test" + File.separator + filePDF.getName() + "_" + renderedImageList.indexOf( i ) + sdf.format( new Date() ) + ".png" ); 
                ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) i, "png", f);
                fileImageList.add( f );
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

        return fileImageList;
    }

}
```

1) Removendo todas as imagens do PDF, utilizando o PDFBox

A principio esse metodo parecia ser a solução final, pois o output (em PDF), era perfeito, mas quando convertia o PDF resultante em imagem atraves do GHOST4J, o arquivo perdia suas configurações e formatações, perdendo alguns caracteres importantes como CPF / CNPJ e também perdendo todos os caracteres especiais.

```
package core;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSBase;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.ContentStreamWriter;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFOperator;

public class PDFRemoveImage {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss");

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static File convert(File in) throws Exception {
        String out = "C:\\Users\\story\\Desktop\\ocr_test" + File.separator + in.getName() + "_" + sdf.format( new Date() ) + ".pdf";

        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(in);

        List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        for( int i=0; i<pages.size(); i++ ) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage)pages.get( i );

            COSDictionary newDictionary = new COSDictionary(page.getCOSDictionary());

            PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page.getContents());
            parser.parse();
            List tokens = parser.getTokens();
            List newTokens = new ArrayList();
            for(int j=0; j<tokens.size(); j++) {
                Object token = tokens.get( j );

                if( token instanceof PDFOperator ) {
                    PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator)token;
                    if( op.getOperation().equals( "Do") ) {
                        COSName name = (COSName)newTokens.remove( newTokens.size() -1 );
                        deleteObject(newDictionary, name);
                        System.out.println( name.getName() );
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                newTokens.add( token );
            }
            PDStream newContents = new PDStream( doc );
            ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter( newContents.createOutputStream() );
            writer.writeTokens( newTokens );
            newContents.addCompression();

            page.setContents( newContents );

            PDResources newResources = new PDResources(newDictionary);
            page.setResources(newResources);
        }

        doc.save(out);
        doc.close();

        return new File( out );
    }

    private static boolean deleteObject(COSDictionary d, COSName name) {
        for(COSName key : d.keySet()) {
            if( name.equals(key) ) {
                d.removeItem(key);
                return true;
            }
            COSBase object = d.getDictionaryObject(key); 
            if(object instanceof COSDictionary) {
                if( deleteObject((COSDictionary)object, name) ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

2) Colocando uma imagem em cima do PDF, utilizando o iText

Depois de mais algum tempo, cheguei nessa solução que que colocava uma imagem sobre a imagem com problema, eu optei por um quadrado preto e o resto do programa funcionou perfeitamente!

```
package core;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;

public class PDFStamper {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss");
    private static final ResourceBundle properties = ResourceBundle.getBundle("properties.configuration");

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static File convert(File in, Class clazz) throws Exception {
        File out = new File( "C:\\Users\\story\\Desktop\\ocr_test" + File.separator + in.getName() + "_" + sdf.format( new Date() ) + ".pdf" );
        try {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader( in.getAbsolutePath() );

            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream(out));

            Image image = Image.getInstance( "C:\\Users\\story\\Desktop\\ocr_test" + File.separator + "replacer.png" );
            for(int i=1; i<= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){
                PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.getOverContent(i);
                if( properties.getString("PDF_STAMP_METHOD").equals("SIMPLE") ){
                    image.setAbsolutePosition(40f, 725f);
                } else if( properties.getString("PDF_STAMP_METHOD").equals("TEMPLATE") ){
                    image.setAbsolutePosition(0f, 0f);
                }
                content.addImage(image);
            }

            pdfStamper.close();

            return out;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Vale destacar que eu adotei a segunda opção como definitiva mas com uma configuração que pode ser avaliada por quem utilizada: no meu caso eu só tinha problemas com apenas uma imagem em um ponto fixo mas caso voce vá ler varios arquivos com diferentes layouts, voce poderá utilizar templates, criando um replacer.png do tamanho do seu PDF.

Observações:

- Para melhorias eu gostaria de implementar um metodo para separar os arquivos PDFs de alguma forma para o uso do template;
- Ou também tentaria pegar todas as imagens do PDF e substituir pelo replacer, mas com exatamente sua altura, largura e posicionamento na tela.
- Ou também tentaria melhorar o uso do PDFBox removendo somente as imagens sem efeitos colaterais ao PDF ou ao processo.
- Pretendo disponibilizar o código completo no GITHUB em breve, quando eu fizer isso, vou deixar o link aqui.